# How to display error message in activity when unique constraint occurs in SQlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, unique-constraint

I am creating an application that consists of a registration form using sqlite database. In this registration form i want to make the username as a unique constraint. But in this i want to display an error toast message in activity when unique usernames was occurred in database.Please let me know how to do it please this is my android DB adapter  activity

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+"USERNAME  text UNIQUE,PASSWORD text); ";
```

After using try catch block in main activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        String dialog_user_name_string = dialog_username.getText().toString();
                        String dialog_pasword_string = dialog_password.getText().toString();
                        String dialog_confirm_string = dialog_confirm.getText().toString();

                        if(dialog_user_name_string.equals("")|| dialog_pasword_string.equals("")||dialog_confirm_string.equals(""))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Some Fileds are empty please fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if(!dialog_pasword_string.equals(dialog_confirm_string))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Passwords did not matched please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if(dialog_pasword_string.equals(dialog_confirm_string))
                        {   **try
                            {
                            loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(dialog_user_name_string, dialog_pasword_string);
                            }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "checking duplicate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**
                        }
                            Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Account created succesfully"+" "+dialog_user_name_string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }   

                });
                registration_dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `insert` code block inside a try catch. Like this

```
try {
    // Your insert code block here
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    // Show error message here
}
```

**EDIT**

```
Button registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_register_button);
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // Execute insert function
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error inserting record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Just in case the above doesn't catch it
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error inserting record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I cant get you dude.Please let me clear where i should use the try catch block weather in Adapter activity or main Activity@Thahzan Mohomed

Comment: You have to use it in your activity which has the registration form. Assuming you have a button to execute the insert function, you'll have to use the try, catch inside the onClickListener of the button.

Comment: I'll try  it and i will catch u later dude

Comment: See my edit. You may have to add another catch block to catch `Exception` just in case the SQLiteConstraintException doesn't catch it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply dude i did it as you said but again same no change, duplication occurs dude..i posted code above.please check it @Thahzan Mohomed

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here dude. Are you using `insert` in your Database handler class? Try `insertOrThrow()` in your `insertEntry` function if so.

Comment: Sorry man, my only remaining idea is to manually check if there's such a username exists in the DB, which is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

insertentry does not give an exception, use  insertOrThrow instead

Comment: Can you provide an explicit method for the questioner?  Details on how they could implement this in their provided code sample?

Comment: you have to edit your answer with some proper coding.